# Pass service account keyfile to go bigquery client

Tags: go, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use service account with go bigquery client. For some reason, there's no Go example of how to pass a service file in when you make a client. I see here https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production but this pattern doesn't follow anything shown. It also isn't shown at https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery

I have

```
//bigquery_caller.go
package main

import "C"
import "fmt"
import "cloud.google.com/go/bigquery"
import "golang.org/x/net/context"


func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, "project-name")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Had an error")
    }

    q := client.Query(`
        select * from mytables
    `)

    it, err := q.Read(ctx)

    fmt.Println(it)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

The code works, I get

```
googleapi: Error 403: Access Denied: Project project-name:
```

How can I pass a service key file in to go client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a service account in your project and furnish a new JSON private key.

Then ensure that the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environmental variable is set to the full path of this file. For example, on Linux:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/user/Downloads/key.json go run main.go
```

As an aside, it is best practice to make sure you protect access to this private key file and ensure the service account has the minimum privileges required to perform its role.

Comment: I'm calling it from a python script, and it'll normally run as part of a flask app. I put that setting in my bash_profile and it still isn't working. Do you know why Go clients can't find that setting in your bash_profile? I've sourced my terminal and no help

Comment: Your bash profile is normally only applied when you start a bash shell. No application that's ran outside a shell session could access any declared variables. Use the `/etc/profile.d` directory (or `/etc/profile`) if you want to make environmental variables available to all processes.

Does it work if you run the Go application and explicitly set the environmental variable as per the example above?

Comment: ya it works like that. putting it in /etc/profile doesnt help either, I can open a different question about the config